# Unable to create/open C++ project in Visual Studio 2015 Community RTM

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

Before installation of RTM version of VS2015 Community Edition I had uninstalled VS2015 Enterprise CTP6 (including applications from "second installer"). There wasn't any problem during installation, but now I'm unable to create/open any C++ project. I receive following error message:

C:\Users\Piotrek\Documents\Visual Studio 14\Projects\Tests\Tests\Tests.vcxproj : error  : Method not found: 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task Microsoft.VisualStudio.Project.IVsUnconfiguredProjectTypeGuidSetter.SetActiveProjectConfigurationAsync(Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.ProjectConfiguration, Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.ProjectConfiguration)'.

I tried to reinstall all related to any VS version stuff, but the problem remains.
Unfortunately, Google knows nothing about SetActiveProjectConfigurationAsync and now I'm stuck. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Check if the Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.v14only.dll assembly is in your GAC (you'll see a similarly-named folder under C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL if it is). It shouldn't be there. But perhaps you have an old version of that assembly in your GAC. If you see any folders in your GAC starting with `Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.*`, move them to a temporary folder and see if it fixes your problem. If it does, delete your temporary folder.

Comment: I removed suggested folders, but it leads to another error message: "The 'Visual C++ Project System Package' package did not load correctly." In ActivityLog.xml i found following info: "<errorinfo>Expected 1 export(s) with contract name "Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.IProjectServiceAccessor" but found 0 after applying applicable constraints.</errorinfo>". Do you know how to rebuild GAC for this specific package? Seems that your suggestion may be good track.

Comment: Hmmm... Do you have VS2013 installed as well? If so, check the folders you moved to the temporary location and move back any version "12" related folders. Then, you should probably "Repair" your VS2015 install to fix things up. I suspect the version "14" files you had in the GAC may have been messing it up.

Comment: I have VS2013 as well, but removed "v14" stuff only. I described antoher approach in this thread , but it failed also. This unique problem seems like good motivation for free update to Windows 10...